# Is it bad practice to manage configuration info for different environments in source code?

Tags: c#, msbuild, app-config, environment, devops

I'm writing a C# app.config file and the file directories are different depending on the target environment. So I have configurations for Debug, Release and a custom one, "Test". I'd love my Configuration to switch the values for file shares and whatnot based on the target environment. Why does MS make it so difficult to do this? I see articles with xml hacks and extensions, but I'm inclined to think if VS doesn't do it natively, it maybe shouldn't be done. In my past life with Java in Eclipse I had a project loaded with these verbose ant build scripts and excessive token replacement that accomplished my goal but created "config hell". We finally gave up managing environment config in source and decided to manage it in, well the target environments. What's the term for this concept / challenge? Am I understanding Configuration Manager incorrectly?

Comment: Have you heard of [config transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Microsoft _might_ only support this natively with `web.config` files (not app.config) but I cannot confirm that.  There is also an ultra popular extension called [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms)

Comment: How are you deploying your code to the various environments? Ideally you'd be using something like [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) which can substitute the correct values for the target environment in the *.config files for you. _Friends shouldn't let friends do right-click Publish to prod._

Comment: Your question is very broad and has some unclear parts. What do you mean by &#39;manage config in target env&#39;? What concept exactly are you searching a term for? How shall we tell if you understand Conf. Mgr. correctly?

Comment: @maccettura it does appear there's more support in the web project types. There's an extension called ConfigurationTransform but I wasn't able to get it working. I'll look at the Cheetah.

Comment: I think @pmcilreavy answers the question, 'Yes'. And since my number of environments and configuration points is very small and doesn't merit a tool like Octopus I think I should just be managing the configuration in the local app.config file in each target environment rather than making my code right-click deploy-able.